# Is there a way to ignore binding override in Toothpick?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, toothpick-di

Say I have scope `S1` which has the module with the binding:

```
bind(Repository.class).to(RepositoryImpl.class).singletonInScope()
```

Then `S2` scope gets opened with `S1` as a parent (`S1 -> S2`) and `S2` defines the same binding (because it's independent and knows nothing of `S1`):

```
bind(Repository.class).to(RepositoryImpl.class).singletonInScope()
```

By default Toothpick overrides parent scope dependencies, so `S2` will have a new `RepositoryImpl` created.

**Question**: Is there a way to reuse the one created in `S1` and ignore an `S2` binding?

This requirement comes from the fact that sometimes there are *independent* application components which reside in different scopes and which share that `Repository` dependency. They know nothing of each other. These components can also be created in different order, depending on the scenario and use case.

So the only rule which I want to impose is this: some component (it is unknown exactly which one) creates `Repository`, all which are created later in current *and* child scopes - reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

To get early opened scope anywhere in your code you can just use

```
Scope s1Scope = Toothpick.openScope('s1-scope-name');
```

In case S1 is parent scope of S2 you can do the same by using getParentScope() method

```
Scope s1Scope = s2Scope.getParentScope();
```

And then just load required singleton from S1 scope

```
Repository s1Repository = s1Scope.getInstance(Repository.class);
```

If you want to do it in the S2 module you can simply do

```
bind(Repository.class).toProviderInstance(() -> Toothpick.openScope('s1-scope-name').getInstance(Repository.class));
```

Comment: So S2 has to know that Repository was created in S1. Is it possible to do this trick without such knowledge? Suppose I have S35 which wants to reuse Repository from S1, do I absolutely have to pass S1's name somehow to S35?

Comment: If I understand well what you mean, you want inject in S35 an instance that is available in S1, so S35 should know about S1, isn't it ?

Comment: In addition, why do you define this binding, without it you, can you just get the repo from S1 ?

Answer (score 0):

When you develop an app built from multi independant components with Toothpick, you may go to this direction :

Every independant component, should own 2 toothpick modules.

- one module that deals with internals dependencies (provided by the module itself)
- one module that deals with externals dependencies (provided at integration level)

In the second one, you will define the in and out dependencies, that will be connected to the others independant components, to build at the end an integrated system of componenet.